# Can "alteration" be used to refer to a spontaneous change, as in "an alteration in ocean temperatures"?

Tags: meaning

I have seen "alteration" being used in contexts such as "to make alterations to a building" or "to make alterations to a plan", where there is a clear agent/cause.

However, I would like to use "alteration" to refer to a seemingly spontaneous change (for instance, "an alteration in prices", "an alteration in ocean temperature", "an alteration in the orbital period of a planet").

Can "alteration" be used in such a context as a perfect synonym of "a change"? Dictionaries define them as equivalent but I am not sure that "alteration" works in such a context.

Comment: I wasn't sure either, but [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alter) says that _alter_ can be both transitive and intransitive.

Comment: It's grammatically fine and makes perfect sense, but I think generally "alteration" has a sense of agency or intentionality to it. I wouldn't call it wrong or even unnatural, just slightly unusual.

Comment: The general notion with climate and temperatures is **change, not alteration**. "alteration" is generally carried out by a human: alter clothing, alter a building, etc.

Comment: Humans alter the environment by polluting it thereby creating climate change. The mussel farmers altered the seawater temperature in the aquaculture bins by installing heaters.